# Warlus Operator conversion

Tags: python, walrus-operator

I have a piece of code involving walrus operator. I am trying to convert it to normal python code. But I am not sure if it is happening correctly or not.

```py
# code with warlus
NUM_ELEMS = cpu_count()
NUM_CORES = len(list_of_data)

fair_core_worload = NUM_ELEMS // NUM_CORES
cores_with_1_more = NUM_ELEMS % NUM_CORES

EXTENTS_OF_SUBRANGES = []
bound = 0

for i, extent_size in enumerate(
    [fair_core_worload + 1 for _ in range(cores_with_1_more)]
    + [fair_core_worload for _ in range(NUM_CORES - cores_with_1_more)]
):
    
    EXTENTS_OF_SUBRANGES.append((bound, bound := bound + extent_size))
```

According to my understanding, it should be working with this code.

```py
for i, extent_size in enumerate(
    [fair_core_worload + 1 for _ in range(cores_with_1_more)]
    + [fair_core_worload for _ in range(NUM_CORES - cores_with_1_more)]
):
    bound = extent_size
    bound_extended = bound + extent_size
    EXTENTS_OF_SUBRANGES.append((bound, bound_extended))
```

I do not have python3.8 to test the walrus code.

Comment: `bound := ...` overwrites `bound`, which your code doesn't do.

Comment: your code overwrites bound with extent_size which the walrus operator doesn't do

Comment: On a side note, there are many online interpreters you can use to execute your `python 3.8` code. This one for example - https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: @deceze: Wont it cause value of bound to change for the 1st parameter too?

Comment: But when "bound" is appened, at that time it is not overwritten right? It gets overwritten after it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> EXTENTS_OF_SUBRANGES.append((bound, bound := bound + extent_size))
> ```

can be destructured into:

```
temp = bound + extent_size
EXTENTS_OF_SUBRANGES.append((bound, temp))
bound = temp
```

Comment: What if the code is like `EXTENTS_OF_SUBRANGES.append((bound, bound+=extent_size`, won't it work the same?  Like using warlus(by original author) has some benefit over this code?

Comment: What does `bound+=extent_size` return in isolation?

Comment: @Ahmad Well, the walrus operator has the benefit of *actually working*. An augmented assignment (`+=`) cannot be used as an expression.

Comment: @shahkalpesh Since it's a statement: nothing.

Comment: @deceze: Yes, it was more of question to Ahmad on why the statement cant be used.

Answer (score 2):

`bound` is getting updated in each iteration by `extent_size`, so you need to keep track of the previous `bound` value:

```py
for i, extent_size in enumerate(
    [fair_core_worload + 1 for _ in range(cores_with_1_more)]
    + [fair_core_worload for _ in range(NUM_CORES - cores_with_1_more)]
):
    prev_bound = bound
    bound += extent_size
    EXTENTS_OF_SUBRANGES.append((prev_bound, bound))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, it should become

```
EXTENTS_OF_SUBRANGES.append((bound, bound + extent_size))
bound = bound + extent_size
```

Comment: You're doing `extent_size + extent_size`, which isn't the same at all.

Comment: OK, now it's merely somewhat repetitive. It's easy to introduce a bug here by changing one operation but not the other. But it generally works as is now, yes.

Comment: @deceze: Do you mean repeating `bound + extent_size` can result into changing one statement but not the other? Yes, agree.